# Can i find an expandablelistview item based on text

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Is this sudo code possible?

```
for (all children in my custom expandable list) {
     if (childItemText.equals("This string") {
           viewWithTextIWant.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue)
     }
}
```

I cannot figure out how to code this. Let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar to this with my app. I've looked through the ExpandableListView widget on the [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) site. It doesn't seem to have any get methods that will allow you to compare the string value of the items in your `ExpandableListView`.

What you'll have to do is create your own array of strings that hold the string values you want. Then use the get method of `ExpandableListView` that returns the position of the item selected and compare it to your string array.

In other words, the get method will return value `"i"`. Use `myStringArray[i].equals("This string")` to compare the string values.

Comment: @yellavon: ExpandedListView has a few "onclick" listeners that you can use. [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html) is probably the one you're looking for. You can put your code into that listener's `onChildClick` function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a task for getChildView in your Adapter class.

I've done the same for groups in my ExpandableListView:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String groupText = (String) ((Map<String,?>) mGroupData.get(groupPosition)).get(KEY);
    View v = groupText.startsWith(SEARCH_TERM) ?
                        mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_1, null) : mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_2, null); 
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mytext);
    tv.setText(groupText);
    return v;       
}
```

Warning! This code is not optimized, it inflates every item, this is expensive. In my case I didn't worry because my ExpandableListView had a few items